# How to create a gui which will show the received sms?

Tags: android, gps, sms, android-manifest

I have an application on first user's phone which sends a sms to second user.I am abled to send the sms to second user but I want to have a button which can show me the received sms.
Right now I'm having a code from a tutorial http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android but it shows the sms immediately after it is received on second user.I want that it is shown only when some particular button like "View sms" is clicked.How can I do it? Any ideas please.

Here is the link of code:

http://pastebin.com/Hu317WNd

Answer (score 2):

You will have to store the message in memory/db/file somewhere and then when the user hits the button you open the file/sql whatever and display the 1st message on the stack.

Listen for button click, get latest message, display.

> Can you give some tutorial links for this or some piece of code it'll
>   be easy then. And one more thing,when that message is retrieved from
>   file can we have a reply option so that user can reply back to it? If
>   yes, please explain how? Or tell me how can I change the above
>   requirement to this one?

I can post some links and you can put them together

[Button Click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) Right at the top

[Reading and writing to a file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) This probably isn't the best way, but you could have a comma delimited file that stores the messages that are waiting to get replied to.
The best way would be a database, but since it seems your a beginner start with a file or maybe even [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

When you read the message in from the file or the db you should have the telephone # data and you can have a reply button present when you display the message.

Comment: Can you give some tutorial links for this or some piece of code it'll be easy then.And one more thing,when that message is retireved from file can we have a reply option so that user can reply back to it?If yes,please explain how?or tell me how can I change the above requirement to this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the tutorial you send, just store the message when it is received in the broadcast listener.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @lan : Please explain a little more about the concept.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of tenants to this problem that can be solved with existing documentation. Look at the last code example in your tutorial. In onReceive, save the message to a variable. Perhaps you could use a vector to store multiple messages. How to link this to a ui is an entirely different question.